# ArrayList returning null value

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, singleton

I'm working on a Java application. 
I create a Singleton class to restrict the instantiation of this class to one object.
In the same class I've got a method which returns an ArrayList of object called GuestAgent.
Here my method:

```
//Singleton class: Tenant
public ArrayList<GuestAgent> gAgentList() {
    final ArrayList<GuestAgent> guestAgents = new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/StackUI/v2.0/";
    url = url + this.tenantId;
    url = url + "/os-agents";

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));
    builder.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", this.tokenId);

    try {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Window.alert("Attenzione si è verificato un errore");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    final HTML respBox = new HTML();
                    respBox.setHTML(response.getText());

                    String risposta = response.getText();

                    JSONValue jsonValue;
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    JSONString jsonString;
                    JSONNumber jsonNumber;

                    jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(risposta);

                    if ((jsonObject = jsonValue.isObject()) == null) {
                        Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                    }

                    jsonValue = jsonObject.get("agents");
                    if ((jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray()) == null) {
                        Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                        GuestAgent guestAgent = new GuestAgent();
                        jsonValue = jsonArray.get(i);

                        if ((jsonObject = jsonValue.isObject()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("agent_id");
                        if ((jsonNumber = jsonValue.isNumber()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setAgentId(jsonNumber.toString());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("architecture");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setArchitecture(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("hypervisor");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setHypervisor(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("md5hash");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setMd5hash(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("os");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setOs(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("url");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setUrl(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("version");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setVersion(jsonString.stringValue());

                        guestAgents.add(guestAgent);
                    }

                } else {
                    // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
                    Window.alert("Errore " + response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusText());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        // Couldn't connect to server   
        Window.alert("Impossibile connettersi al server");
    }

    return guestAgents;
}
```

Method activation from other class:

```
//Other class
ArrayList<GuestAgent> agents;
agents = Tenant.getTenantObject().gAgentList();
Window.alert(Integer.toString(agents.size()));
```

At this point, I've found out that `agents` list is empty. Hope someone will help.
Giacomo.

Comment: If there is no errors the only way to get empty list is an empty jsonArray . Add a check if(jsonArray.length == 0) {alert("empty json");}

Comment: I've checked jsonArray and it's not empty. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Looks like asynchronous code, maybe sendrequest is asynchrosous if that is the case you have to wait for the request to be done before returning your list. Check what object is returned by sendRequest there should be some logic there to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call made by `RequestBuilder` is asyncronous, meaning that, after calling `builder.sendRequest`, it takes some time to run one of the two callbacks methods `onError` and `onResponseReceived`.

Your problem is that you correctly start the async process, but you are returning the guestAgents array **immediately**! (look at the very last line of your code). At this point the result of the async call is not yet ready and the array is still empty.

Methods like this usually don't provide a return value, but they take a callback function as argument that will be called when the process finishes and will contain the resulting values. In other words, you always need to wait the request to be fully completed before accessing the `guestAgents` array.

I would do it this way (I did it with a simple notepad without compiling, there could be errors...):

```
//Other class
ArrayList<GuestAgent> agents;
agents = Tenant.getTenantObject().gAgentList(new AgentsResultCallback {
    void onCompleted(ArrayList<GuestAgent> agents) {
        // here we have the result!
        if (agents != null) { // check for errors 
            Window.alert(Integer.toString(agents.size()));
        }
    }
});
```

The singleton:

```
//Singleton class: Tenant   (LOOK AT THE VOID RETURN VALUE!)
public void gAgentList(final AgentsResultCallback callback) {
    final ArrayList<GuestAgent> guestAgents = new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/StackUI/v2.0/";
    url = url + this.tenantId;
    url = url + "/os-agents";

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));
    builder.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", this.tokenId);

    try {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Window.alert("Attensione si è verificato un errore");
                callback.onCompleted(null); // call the callback with null results 
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    final HTML respBox = new HTML();
                    respBox.setHTML(response.getText());

                    String risposta = response.getText();

                    JSONValue jsonValue;
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    JSONString jsonString;
                    JSONNumber jsonNumber;

                    jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(risposta);

                    if ((jsonObject = jsonValue.isObject()) == null) {
                        Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                    }

                    jsonValue = jsonObject.get("agents");
                    if ((jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray()) == null) {
                        Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                        GuestAgent guestAgent = new GuestAgent();
                        jsonValue = jsonArray.get(i);

                        if ((jsonObject = jsonValue.isObject()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("agent_id");
                        if ((jsonNumber = jsonValue.isNumber()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setAgentId(jsonNumber.toString());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("architecture");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setArchitecture(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("hypervisor");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setHypervisor(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("md5hash");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setMd5hash(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("os");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setOs(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("url");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setUrl(jsonString.stringValue());

                        jsonValue = jsonObject.get("version");
                        if ((jsonString = jsonValue.isString()) == null) {
                            Window.alert("Error parsing the JSON");
                        }
                        guestAgent.setVersion(jsonString.stringValue());

                        guestAgents.add(guestAgent);


                    }

                        // FINISHED! results are complete so I send them to the callback
                        callback.onCompleted(guestAgents);

                } else {
                    // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
                    Window.alert("Errore " + response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusText());
                    callback.onCompleted(null); // call the callback with null results here, too
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        // Couldn't connect to server   
        Window.alert("Impossibile connettersi al server");
    }

    return; // return nothing!
}
```

And the small declaration of the callback class:

```
abstract public class AgentsResultCallback {
    abstract void onCompleted(ArrayList<GuestAgent> agents);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I catch the problem. How should I implement the callback function you are talking about? Have you some example code?

Comment: Ah, un'altra cosa... Attensione => Attenzione  ;)

Comment: Thank you!!I'm keen on solving my problem! Non ho afferrato "Attensione => Attenzione"??? :D

Comment: Hai scritto "Attensione si è verificato un errore"!

Comment: Mio dio, non l'avevo notato!!Grazie! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're confused by the asynchronism. Here's how it works, chonologically

1. You create an empty list
2. You send an HTTP request
3. You return the list
4. The caller displays the size of the list: 0
5. some time later, when the response to the request comes back, the `onResponseReceived()` callback method is called and adds elements to the list.

The method should not return a list, since it will always be empty. Instead, the code displaying the list should be called from the `onResponseReceived()` method, once you have actually received the HTTP response and populated the list.